# Definition of unique measure

Tags: stochastic-processes, definition, finance

In the [*Notes on Stochastic Finance*](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/indext.html) by Nicolas Privault, we can find that

> when the risk-neutral probability measure is unique, the market is said to be *complete*.

To say that a measure is unique we must have a notion of equivalent measures.

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ - measurable space. Let $a,b$ - measures.

In the context above, which equivalence notion is used?

1. Measure $a$ is equivalent to $b$ when 
   $$\forall_{S\in\Sigma}\;a(S)=b(S)$$

or

2. Measure $a$ is equivalent to $b$ when 
   $$a\ll b \land b\ll a$$ where $\ll$ denotes the absolute continuity of measures.

Comment: I think I will stand for the first definition of equivalence, as measures are just functions and your first definition is just the equality of functions.